# wikimedia api page content not displaying

Tags: mediawiki

Im using the following to display wikipedia page content but my page is blank. The page it's displaying on is https://localrealtors.com/wiki/.... Any ideas? Thanks.

for php code I am using:

```
// load Zend classes
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Rest_Client');

// define category prefix
$url = 'httpd.apache.org';

try {
  // initialize REST client
  $wikipedia = new Zend_Rest_Client('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php');

  // set query parameters
  $wikipedia->action('query');
  $wikipedia->list('exturlusage');
  $wikipedia->euquery($url);
  $wikipedia->eulimit('30');
  $wikipedia->eunamespace('0');
  $wikipedia->format('xml');

  // perform request
  // iterate over XML result set
  $result = $wikipedia->get();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

For the Output I am using :

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h2>Search results for pages referencing URL 
      '<?php echo $url; ?>'</h2>
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($result->query->exturlusage->eu as $r): ?>
      <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/
      <?php echo $r['title']; ?>"><?php echo $r['title']; ?>
      </a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the data returned by the query?